DIfference between embedding and homomorphism of an L-structure
I am using "An invitation to Model Theory" by Jonathan Kirby to learn model theory. So an $L$-structure has relations, functions and constants on a certain domain. Definition of embedding of an $L$-structure by the author:
Let $\cal{A}$ and $\cal{B}$ be $L$-structures. An embedding of $L$-structures from $\cal{A}$ to $\cal{B}$ is an injective function $\pi:A \mapsto B$ such that:

For all relation symbols $R$ of $L$, and all $a_1,...,a_n \in A$,
$$ (a_1,...,a_n) \in R^{\cal{A}} \ \  \text{iff} \ \ (\pi (a_1),...,\pi (a_n)) \in R^{\cal{B}}.$$

For all function symbols $f$ of $L$, and all $a_1,...,a_n \in A$,
$$ \pi(f^{\cal{A}}(a_1,...,a_n)) = f^{\cal{B}}(\pi (a_1),...,\pi (a_n)).$$

For all constant symbols $c$ of $L$, $\ \pi(c^{\cal{A}}) = c^{\cal{B}}$.


In an exercise, an homomorphism is also defined. The two differences with the definition of an embedding are that $\pi(\cdot)$ is not necessarily injective, and that the iff of the relations part is changed to an if-then. I have no problem with the injectivity part, but I am struggling to find a reason for the second difference. Even more, I can't think of an instance where $(\pi (a_1),...,\pi (a_n)) \in R^{\cal{B}}$ but $(a_1,...,a_n)) \notin R^{\cal{A}}$, because the function $\pi(\cdot)$ is defined to go from one domain to the other, namely from $A$ to $B$.
I am specifically looking for an example where the if-then condition is met but not the iff.

"injective", not "inyective"

Consider the language with one binary relation symbol $R$. Let $A=\{a,a'\}$ with $R^A=\varnothing$, and let $B=\{b,b'\}$ with $R^B=\{(b,b')\}$.
Then every map $A\to B$ is a homomorphism, but none of them is an embedding.
